# Can't boot Windows 7

Tags: windows, boot

I just bought a new computer, this is the specs:

> ASUS M52AD-XTREME-NR005T Intel i5-4460 / 8GB / 2TB / GTX960 2GB

I burned a copy of Windows 7 on a DVD and want to install it on my new computer, but when I choose to boot the disc it is ignored and I just boot into the pre-installed Windows 10 instead. I tried this with a Ubuntu disc as well and that one boots fine. The Windows 7 DVD boots normally on my other computer.

What can I do?

Comment: theoretical windows disc? Did you try it or not? is it a flash drive? please be more specific, since this may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: As I said its a cd disc that works on my other computer

Comment: Your question is very unclear, please clarify what you are asking... Did you try installing Windows 7 on the machine and have problems? Or are you wondering if you will have problems? A windows installation disc does not care what computer it is in if that's what you are wondering... It will work the same on any standard computer...

If you're wondering whether your computer supports Windows 7, you will have to figure out what motherboard model is in it (not the computer name, motherboard name) and see if that supports Windows 7 (if yes, then your computer supports W7)

Comment: Is this a legitimate copy of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of for this to happen (if I correctly understood the question) would be secure boot. Is Secure boot enabled in your BIOS? (If so, you have to disable it to be able to boot Windows 7).

If this was not the problem, then there are I guess many details that vary from BIOS to BIOS that can cause issues like this. In which case I recommend you try another approach (such as installing from USB, to burn a Windows 7 installation iso to USB I suggest you use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)).

If this is not an option then try finding other ways to force your system to boot the DVD (I know this is an ASUS motherboard, in the UEFI BIOS if you go to advanced settings and the boot options, at the bottom you will probably find "boot override" options, try using this. I happen to be an avid user of ASUS motherboards and the boot override function has sometimes solved cases like this for me.)